# i have created a custom css but the same css is not getting generated in pub/static/version in custom theme

Tags: magento2

I have created a custom css but the same css is not getting generated in pub/static/version in custom theme.

Comment: What is your css location and how did you add it? Update the code to question

Comment: @Arjun  Can you share folder structure and which file you included you're css

Comment: Have you run deploy command? Is that any error or run successfully?

Comment: My car isn't running properly. Any idea what's wrong?

My point is, you haven't given any information to enable anybody to help you.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add your css in both file (App and pub) or you need to run commands.
php bin/magento static:content:deploy